# What is the equivalent of the onSubmitFail from 'redux-form'

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

https://final-form.org/docs/

onSubmitFail does not seem to exist in react-final-form, is there an equivalent or a work around?

In redux-form you could pass an onSubmitFail fail prop

```
AfterCheckoutForm = reduxForm({
  form: formName,
  destroyOnUnmount: false,

  onSubmitFail: errors => {
    scrollToErrors();
  }
})(AfterCheckoutForm);
```

Answer (score 1):

No, but there is a solution specifically tailored to scroll to errors.

Check out [`final-form-focus`](https://github.com/final-form/final-form-focus#-final-form-focus-).